# ExtJs - Combobox and hidden fields

Tags: extjs, combobox, hidden

I have a problem with showing hidden field value.
My code:

```
var MyComboBox = Ext.extend(Ext.form.ComboBox, {
initComponent : function() {
    Ext.apply(this, { 
        store           : Store ,

        displayField   : 'name',
        valueField     : 'id',

        typeAhead      : true,
        mode           : 'local',
        forceSelection : true,
        triggerAction  : 'all',
        selectOnFocus  : true
    });
    MyComboBox.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
}
});


// Select event.
var combo1 = new MyComboBox({
    name        : 'combo1',
    applyTo     : 'combo1',
    hiddenName  : 'hcombo1',    // hidde field
    hiddenValue : 'id',

    listeners : {
        'select' : function() {
            combo2.setValue(combo1.getValue());
        }
    }
});

var combo2 = new MyComboBox({
    name      : 'combo2',
    applyTo   : 'combo2',
    listeners : {
        'select' : function() {
            alert(combo1.getRawValue()); // print hidden value (id of record)
        }
    }
});
```

**I need value of hidden field with name - hcombo1. But code alert(combo1.getRawValue()) - print not ID, they print NAME. What I do wrong ?
ExtJS 3.3.1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try change your listeners like this :

```
listeners : {
    'select' : function(combo) {
        combo2.setValue(combo.getValue());
    }
}
```

from docs, event "select" can passed 3 argument
`select : ( Ext.form.ComboBox combo, Ext.data.Record record, Number index )`

Comment: Thank you very much. in this example to work. 

But in the case when the second combobox to create the first so do not get to pass id first combobox.

I try so

    Ext.get ('id'). Dom.value = Ext.get ('comp_name'). GetValue ();

How to get a hidden element value?

Comment: sorry, i didn't get it,... i don't know what you mean...when combo1 selected, the combo2's value changed , when combo2 selected, it change combo1's value ?? or what?

Comment: thanks for the help) I figured out. I had to take a hidden field with combobox. I tried to take with Ext.get, but had to Ext.getCmp)